# Running a simple shell script as a cronjob

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a very simple shell script I need to run as a cronjob but I can't get even the test scripts to run. Here's and example script:

/home/myUser/scripts/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
touch file.txt
```

crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/myUser/scripts/test.sh
```

The script runs fine from the terminal but can't get it to run as a cronjob. So far I've tried these in crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * /bin/bash /home/myUser/scripts/test.sh
```

And this in the the script file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/myUser/scripts
```

From what I've gathered the solution might be in the PATH variable but I can't figure out what it is since my understanding is very limited at this point. So my question is, how do I get my scripts to run as cronjobs?

**EDIT:** the file has rwx permissions for all users. This is just for testing purposes.

**EDIT:** cronjobs such as `* * * * * touch /home/myUser/scripts/test.txt` work but it wont run scripts.

Comment: I would add that you specify your shell as `/bin/sh` in the crontab (which is the default) however your script wants a bash shell (different to sh). Check to see if running your script using `sh yourScript.sh` still works?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What directory is file.txt in? cron runs jobs in your home directory, so unless your script `cd`s somewhere else, that's where it's going to look for/create file.txt.

EDIT: When you refer to a file without specifying its full path (e.g. `file.txt`, as opposed to the full path `/home/myUser/scripts/file.txt`) in shell, it's taken that you're referring to a file in your current working directory. When you run a script (whether interactively or via crontab), the script's working directory has nothing at all to do with the location of the script itself; instead, it's inherited from whatever ran the script.

Thus, if you `cd` (change working directory) to the directory the script's in and then run it, `file.txt` will refer to a file in the same directory as the script. But if you don't `cd` there first, `file.txt` will refer to a file in whatever directory you happen to be in when you ran the script. For instance, if your home directory is /home/myUser, and you open a new shell and immediately run the script (as `scripts/test.sh` or `/home/myUser/scripts/test.sh`; `./test.sh` won't work), it'll touch the file /home/myUser/file.txt because /home/myUser is your current working directory (and therefore the script's).

When you run a script from `cron`, it does essentially the same thing: it runs it with the working directory set to your home directory. Thus all file references in the script are taken relative to your home directory, unless the script `cd`s somewhere else or specifies an absolute path to the file.

Comment: file.txt is in the same directory as the test.sh script.

Comment: There's the problem then. Add `/home/myUser/scripts` to the script (or change the touch command to `touch /home/myUser/scripts/file.txt`).

Comment: This fixed the problem. Could you tell me why the full path to the file was required?

Comment: I am getting this error "sh: 0: Can't open /root/scritps/cron_job.sh", when trying to execute sh file from cronjob like "*/1 * * * *  sh /root/scritps/cron_job.sh >> /tmp/cron.output 2>&1".FYI: cron_job.sh doing echo only. any idea what is the issue here ?

Comment: @BipinVayalu is "scritps" a typo for "scripts"?

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way would be to use a GUI:

For Gnome use *gnome-schedule (universe)*

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

For KDE use *kde-config-cron*

```
It should be pre installed on Kubuntu
```

But if you use a headless linux or don´t want GUI´s you may use:

```
crontab -e
```

If you type it into Terminal you´ll get a table.
You have to insert your cronjobs now.
Format a job like this:

```
*     *     *     *     *  YOURCOMMAND
-     -     -     -     -
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     +----- Day in Week (0 to 7) (Sunday is 0 and 7)
|     |     |     +------- Month (1 to 12)
|     |     +--------- Day in Month (1 to 31)
|     +----------- Hour (0 to 23)
+------------- Minute (0 to 59)
```

There are some shorts, too (if you don´t want the *):

```
@reboot --> only once at startup
@daily ---> once a day
@midnight --> once a day at midnight
@hourly --> once a hour
@weekly --> once a week
@monthly --> once a month
@annually --> once a year
@yearly --> once a year
```

If you want to use the shorts as cron (because they don´t work or so):

```
@daily --> 0 0 * * *
@midnight --> 0 0 * * *
@hourly --> 0 * * * *
@weekly --> 0 0 * * 0
@monthly --> 0 0 1 * *
@annually --> 0 0 1 1 *
@yearly --> 0 0 1 1 *
```

Comment: The cronjob is already running once a minute (* * * * *) but its not executing the script.

Comment: Is the line ending with an `whitespace` ?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. See the second edit. Crontab doesn't run scripts but it works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Try,

```
 # cat test.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 /bin/touch file.txt
```

cron as:

```
 * * * * * /bin/sh /home/myUser/scripts/test.sh
```

And you can confirm this by:

```
 # tailf /var/log/cron
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify complete path and grant proper permission to scriptfile. I tried following script file to run through cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/mkdir /scratch/ofsaaweb/CHEF_FICHOME/ficdb/bin/crondir
```

And crontab command is

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /scratch/ofsaaweb/CHEF_FICHOME/ficdb/bin/test.sh
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should run properly at cron also. Please check below things.

1- You are editing proper file to set cron.

2- You have given proper permission(execute permission) to script mean your script is executable.