# MongoDB - Run script with Crontab

Tags: mongodb, cron

I have a script I want to update every day. So I have to use a crontab. How can I run the script using the Crontab?

**UPDATE**

i use ubuntu.

[script file](https://gist.github.com/forguta/05882ac08ad1e5c8e74ad6d6c5be771e)

Comment: write a bash file that runs the query through MongoDB and then schedule the bash (.sh) file in cronjob with crontab. what version of linux are you using and please post your bash file

Comment: This should resolve your queries.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754784/running-a-simple-shell-script-as-a-cronjob

Comment: I will examine and try. @RahulLakhanpal

Comment: Is there a sample created with the MongoDB script you can use as an example? @user3299379

Comment: here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837673/how-to-execute-mongo-commands-through-shell-scripts. this is a really bad question you have asked as you haven't provided any sample code or even put an example of the query you're trying to run

Comment: i add script file for you @user3299379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to update using you bash script everyday at 12:15am.
Then add an entry into `/etc/crontab` like this

```
15 0 * * * /home/your_bash_script.sh
```

Just for additional information, the time entries in cron are added as

```
* * * * * * <your-bash-script-path>
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

Comment: I have no problem for cron. I have a problem creating my bash file only. How to convert any script file to bash?

Comment: You are using ubuntu, so any file that uses bash commands and has a .sh file extension in the end is a bash script.